# PHP loading order

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

How can I load 'includes/part1' after 'includes/part2'?

Here is a sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Txt</h1>
    <div>
        <?php get_template_part('includes/part1'); ?>
    </div>
    <h1>Txt</h1>
    <div>
        <?php get_template_part('includes/part2'); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

That's what I have on my page.
I want browser to load first 'includes/part2' and then 'includes/part1'.

Comment: will u please elaborate on your question?

Comment: You will need to put that line at the bottom of your code.  PHP is not very asynchronous language.

Comment: You can use ajax to load this content after loading whole page

Answer (score 1):

Agreed without any context it's hard to help you.

If Bas Kuis method is not what you require then perhaps this is

You can set it in a buffer using ob_start() and then set it and then set it as a variable using $foo = ob_get_contents(). and finally echo the result using echo $foo.

```
ob_start();

get_template_part('includes/part');

$foo = ob_get_contents();

ob_clean();

echo $foo;
```

Here is an example of using a php buffer

[PHP ob_start](http://ideone.com/ka9L2f)

However i'm not too sure what you would gain from this.

Comment: Wouldn't this accomplish the opposite?

Comment: This would execute the 'includes/part' php script before the contents are send to the browser.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply include it at the bottom of your page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Page</h1>
        <p>Stuff</p>
    </body>
</html>
<?php get_template_part('includes/part'); ?>
```

Or..

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Page</h1>
        <p>Stuff</p>
        <div><?php get_template_part('includes/part'); ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If that is more relevant.

If you need to run something once the dom is fully loaded and ready to manipulated you could:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $().ready(function(){
                $.get("includes/part");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Page</h1>
        <p>Stuff</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Either way - you'll have to provide some more context on what you're trying to do.